# Remove multiple files using multithreading in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, optimization, file-io

My application generates a lot of log files, I want to clean this folder each time I startup the application. The simplest way to do that is:

```java
//remove files from the previous executions
Thread tCleanAppFolder = new Thread() {

    public void run() {

        String savePath = getFilesDir().getPath() + File.separator;
        File path = new File(savePath);

        for (File file : path.listFiles()) {
            file.delete();
        }
    }
};
tCleanAppFolder.start();
```

Of course, we execute this code in the separate thread for the performance reasons.

My questions:

1. Should I remove each file in the separate thread or it's OK to leave the code as it's now?
2. Will the usage of the multiple threads inside of `tCleanAppFolder` thread boost the cleaning process?

Probably, it's worth to mention, I'm talking about Android application thus, there is no HDD, but internal and external memory of a smartphone.

Comment: No one has mention that I/O calls are already buffered, I would take a guess that that if you have started new threads everytime you saw the possiblity it would slow down the larger application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure you are not constructing any new files before
your 'file deleting' thread executes this `path.listFiles()` ?

if not you might delete files that are currently needed !

apart from that spinning of some more threads would probably improve performance since in each iteration of the loop you will have a lot of IO-Time. In other words ... your thread is not CPU-bound but IO-bound, so spinning of more threads than you have CPU cores might pay off.

on the other hand you should not start thousands of threads if it might happen that you have thousands of files. in that case your logic would be a bit more complex to distribute the files to delete over the threads.

Answer (score 2):

Don't prematurely optimize until you know for sure that this code is a bottleneck. The time can always be spent fixing another bug or adding another feature.

Making it multi-threaded will make your application state more complex and thus harder to debug and the source code harder to read. So before you do this, I would run benchmarks to actually determine whether or not this operation is thread-bound and could actually be optimized by using more threads.

Comment: Exactly, don't blindly try to optimize. +1

Comment: Ask a lot of question to learn how well some parts of a system are multithreading optimized and its usefull. If you don't know the answer please stop this nonsense text. It doesn't help at all, remember you don't only answer for the guy who ask the question but for everyone who gets this as a top google hit. And i would love to know if the kernel can optimize parallel file deletes in a directory - 8 years later.

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply deleting files (cpu-wise the time needed is negligible and individually it is the same from the i/o point of view too) the bottleneck will be represented by disk I/O, i don't expect to see any improvement deleting file with multiple threads, you can just do it sequentially.

Comment: Why are you so sure that this task can't be parallelized at the HDD's controller level? On my SSD-based laptop multi-threaded deletion works 2x times faster (for any amount of files from 1000 to 60000). However it doesn't boost up with three or more threads.

Comment: At controller level i'd say it depends on the disk internal structure, so yes, more than one concurrent operation could be possible (SSDs are a perfect example of this). So, what you saw is likely an indication of an SSD able to perform multiple parallel operation of physically separate NAND blocks. Other than this, soon, with fast enough disks, the cpu time needed to perform specific fast atomic i/o operations could be no more negligible  respect to i/o in languages like Java(considering all the layers of code you need to traverse), so it could make sense to start using more than one thread.

Comment: @user3707125 This corresponds with my experience reading directory tree (nearly threefold speed), both on SSD and HDD. I guess, it comes from enqueuing multiple commands so that the OS or the controller are able to plan ahead. So it should somewhat help even when no parallelism is available.

Comment: Update to the question:
Probably, it's worth to mention, I'm talking about Android application thus, there is no HDD, but internal and external memory of a smartphone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to start the log file afresh instaed of appending the current log you can use

```
<appender name="RFA" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
<param name="Append" value="false" />
```

I use this during my development 
This does not delete or clean if the log file is rolled.